# Simple formatter and trying to create custom formatting style around code?

Tags: pharo

I'm trying to create a custom, or modify the existing, method formatter to experiment with different styles of arranging code.

BISimpleFormatter is a subclass of RBProgramNodeVisitor so I plan to use something like that too.

As a generic starting point, how can I insert my own characters(spaces or tabs) before and after each code node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of `BISimpleFormatter`. For every `#visit<XYZ>` method in the `BISimpleFormatter` implement in your class the same method by doing whatever pre-decoration you want, then call `super visit<XYZ>` and end with your post-decoration.

For instance,

**`MySpaciousFormatter`** could do something on the lines of

```
visitLiteralNode: aLiteralNode
  codeStream space.
  super visitLiteralNode: aLiteralNode.
  codeStream space
```

This way every time the formatter is about to print a `LiteralNode` it will put spaces around it. I'm sure you have much better ideas; I just wanted to give you a simple example.